# Will using subprocess.run() in a pytest function cause any testing problems?

Tags: python, pytest

I have the following Python module I want to test:

```py
import sys

def greet():
    print(f"Hello, {sys.argv[1]}!")
```

I have set it up as a script entry point, such that this works:

```sh
$ greet World
Hello, World!
```

Now, I want to test with [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/).

It works to make a `tests/test_greet.py` file with the following:

```py
import subprocess

import greet

def test_greet_cli():
    result = subprocess.run(["greet", "World"], capture_output=True)
    assert b"Hello, World!" in result.stdout
```

Will this cause any problems?

Are there alternative ways of testing this that I should consider?

Feel free to browse [my article](https://dev.to/bowmanjd/build-command-line-tools-with-python-poetry-4mnc) in which I document something similar to the above. I suggest two ways of writing the test in that article, one of which is this way. I don't want to include it if it could cause any problems.

Comment: its not the best idea, but also not the worst. However, all of the cli tools (optparse, click, there are others) have provisions for executing the cli app inline for testing. (also, this is opinion based, and is not within the scope of stackoverflow)

Comment: Apropos your article... it's missing flag handling.. maybe have a look at invoke? (http://www.pyinvoke.org/)

Comment: @PaulBecotte, thanks for flagging the potentially opinion-based nature of this. I will see if I can reword the question. I am really after: will this break anything, or are there features I have missed that I could be using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fundamental problem is that this function

```
def greet():
    print(f"Hello, {sys.argv[1]}!")
```

is "bad" when it comes to testability, since it relies on global variables. A much better version would be something like:

```
def greet(args=None):
    if args is None:
        args = sys.argv
    print(f"Hello, {args[1]}!")
```

This would have the same functionality, but would be much easier to test.

Comment: I love the conversation. I am not sure the second example removes the global variables though, if you believe that sys.argv is a global variable. Feel free to explain further.

Comment: In the second example you can test the function by injecting the dependencies. "dependency injection" is just a fancy name for passing the external requirements as parameters to the function. Remember that you're testing your own code, not sys.argv... You can also do dependency injection by mocking sys.argv (pytest has a monkeypatch fixture that will do this). I just find it more straight-forward to use arguments (less typing when creating tests).